# Android Studio 2.1: error: package org.junit does not exist

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit

**Update**: Its a bug and it's been reported, please star:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=209832&thanks=209832&ts=1463161330

I'm setting up unit testing on Android studio.

I have read [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/testing/start/index.html#config-local-tests) and set it up exactly as specified. I have my test folder set up as `src/test/java`

I've made a random test class:
[image]

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;

public class RandomTestClass
{
    @Test
    public void testTest()
    {
        assertThat(4, is(4));
    }
}
```

However when I go to run my test I get:

> error: package org.junit does not exist

I've set up my gradle EXACTLY as descibed in the docs:

```
dependencies {
    // Required -- JUnit 4 framework
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // Optional -- Mockito framework
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
}
```

The few other questions with this issue seemed to say these dependencies are missing. I have them.

Can you think of any reason my Local Unit Tests are not finding the junit file when I go to run the test?

**Note**
It's able to find the junit classes when Im writing the code. It only can't find junit when I run the test.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Gradle is not doing it's job.

[Manually adding the jars](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Download-and-Install) fixed the problem.

Comment: I was very hopeful about this solution but it did not solve it for me

Comment: For now use `compile`. It is the only other way it will work

Answer (score 31):

I changed TestCompile to androidTestCompile and it's worked without problems.

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

to

```
androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Comment: testCompile is for the `test` directory, androidTestCompile is for the `androidTest` one

Answer (score 5):

add this dependency to solve your issue

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Answer (score 2):

Some things you should check -

- Do you have unit test and debug selected under build variants?
- Is your working directory set to $MODULE_DIR$ in Run/Debug configurations for the unit test?
- Did you create the test by selecting the class you wish to test, going to Navigate -> Test and having Android Studio construct the test class for you?

Comment: I don't know what you mean build variants. ` $MODULE_DIR$` is set as the working directory. Using the Navigate->Test to create the test had no effect but I tried it.

Comment: Hmm. Want to help but not sure this is something I could diagnose without seeing the actual code base (this seems like some sort of environmental issue). Maybe someone with more experience than me can chime in if they've seen this behavior before. 

RE: build variants, you can access the build variants menu in the bottom left part of the screen, just above favorites

Answer (score 2):

My tests are in `src/test/java` folder and adding `test.setRoot('test')` to `sourceSets` worked for me.

```
sourceSets {
    test.setRoot('test')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the Build Variant to `debug`.

`View -> Tool Windows -> Build Variants`

UPD: This actually may be the cause, when all `gradle` dependencies are met, but `org.junit.Test` still not found. At least it was a cause for me. It was not working in 'release' build type, but was working in 'debug'.

Answer (score -1):

Download (junit-4.12.jar) from 
https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Download-and-Install 
and copy it in your libs folder:(`yourProjectFolder/app/libs`)

and then in build.gradle(`Module: app`) use this codes:

```
dependencies {
...
compile files('libs/junit-4.12.jar')
...
}
```

then rebuild your project.